# Trying to use LZO Compression with MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, compression, hadoop-lzo

I want to use LZO compression in MapReduce, but am getting an error when I run my MapReduce job. I am using Ubuntu with a Java program. I am only trying to run this on my local machine. My initial error is

```
ERROR lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Could not load native gpl library
```

and down the line

```
ERROR lzo.LzoCodec: Cannot load native-lzo without native-hadoop
```

and then

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: native-lzo library not available
```

I have followed a number of online and textual instructions on how to download and configure files for use with LZO compression. Here you can see my hadoop-lzo jar file in the `lib` folder

[image]

I have changed my configurations as such. Here is my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
        <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
    <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.output.compress</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.output.compression.codec</name>
    <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

and my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
    <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.env</name>
    <value>JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/matthew/hadoop/lib/native/lib/lib</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I have also modified my hadoop-env.sh in the same conf folder with these lines

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.4.13.jar
export JAVA_LIBRARY=/home/hadoop/lib/native/lib/lib
```

If you are interested in what is in `/home/hadoop/lib/native/lib/lib`

[image]

For what it's worth, here is my Driver class that does all of the compressing

```
//import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
//import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
//import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec;
import com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class FuzzyJoinDriver extends Configured implements Tool{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {     
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new  FuzzyJoinDriver(),args);
System.exit(exitCode);
}
@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
          System.err.println("Usage: FuzzyJoinDriver <input path> <output path>");
          System.exit(-1);
        }

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        //Used to compress map output
        //conf.setBoolean("mapred.compres.map.output", true);
        //conf.setClass("mapred.map.output.compression.code", GzipCodec.class, CompressionCodec.class);
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(FuzzyJoinDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("Fuzzy Join");

        //Distributed Cache
        //DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/cache/ReducerCount.txt"),  job.getConfiguration());


        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(FuzzyJoinMapper.class);


        job.setReducerClass(FuzzyJoinReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(RelationTuple.class);


        job.setPartitionerClass(JoinKeyPartitioner.class);


        job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        //Used to compress output from reducer
        FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job,  true);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, LzopCodec.class);
        //SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressionType(job, org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.CompressionType.BLOCK);

        return(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

It compiles with no errors.

I worry that my lack of understanding of the configuration and other steps is leading me down the wrong path and perhaps I'm missing something simple to those with a better comprehension of the matter than I have. Thanks for making it this far. I know it's a lengthy post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following properties in your mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
```

If you want to do it on a job per job basis, you could also directly implement that in your code in 1 of the following ways:

```
conf.set("mapred.compress.map.output", "true")
conf.set("mapred.map.output.compression.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec");
```

or

```
jobConf.setMapOutputCompressorClass(LzoCodec.class);
```

Comment: First and foremost: thank you for taking the time to answer. This question isn't receiving the activity I had hoped. If you see from my driver class, I am not even trying to compress the intermediate output, just the output of the reducer. Do you still think I need to add this property?

Comment: not sure, according to me Yes and not forget to restart hadoop after the change. Also make sure that you have both 32-bit and 64-bit liblzo2 installed.

Comment: more info, https://github.com/toddlipcon/hadoop-lzo       and    

https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/hadoop-gpl-compression/wiki/FAQ?redir=1

Comment: How do I install both 32 and 64 bit liblzo2?

Comment: hat you must have both 32-bit and 64-bit liblzo2 installed

Comment: see this blog--- https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/hadoop-gpl-compression/wiki/FAQ?redir=1

Comment: I only have a 64 bit jdk. Will I need to get a 32 bit jdk as well?

Comment: not sure but after reading the blog, You have both 32 and 64 bit jdk

Comment: I can't seem to find a 32 bit jdk on my machine, but I did see how to install it. The blog is not the best-written piece of literature I've ever read, but I will try to navigate through it and get back to you.